# How to Test AngularJS Jasmine encapsulated promises

Tags: angularjs, mocking, jasmine, promise, karma-jasmine

Maybe someone might help me out with testing a mocked Service with chained promises.

### Factory to Test

```
app.factory('factory', [ 'service', function( service ){

 var baz;

 return {
     updateMe: function( updateObj ){

           // do stuff with updateObj

         console.log( updateObj ); 
         // { name: 'Mr. Nobody', _id: '1', _rev: '2' }

           return service.save( updateObj )
               .then( function( result ) {

         console.log( result ); 
         // { name: 'Mr. Foo', _id: '1', _rev: '1' } but should be 
         // { name: 'Mr. Nobody', _id: '1', _rev: '2' }

                   return service.get( result.id )
                        .then( function( getResult ){

                             // do stuff with getResult
                             var index = baz
                                           .map( function(e) { return e.doc._id; } )
                                           .indexOf( getResult._id );

                             baz.splice(index, 1);
                             baz.splice(index, 0, {doc:getResult});

                        });

                });
      },
     saveMe: function( saveObj ){

           // do stuff with saveObj

           return service.save( saveObj )
               .then( function( result ) {

                         saveObj._rev = result.rev;
                         saveObj = { 'doc': saveObj };

                         baz.push( saveObj );

                });
      }
  };
 }]);
```

### Test and Mock

```
inject( function ( _$q_, _$rootScope_, _service_) {

     $q = _$q_;
     deferred = $q.defer();
     $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
     service = _service_;

}

spyOn(service, 'save').and.callFake(

     function( saveObj ) {

         console.log( saveObj ); 
         // { name: 'Mr. Foo'} or 
         // { name: 'Mr. Nobody', _id: '1', _rev: '2' }


         // do Stuff
         deferred.resolve( result );
         return deferred.promise;

     }

 );
spyOn(service, 'get').and.callFake(

     function( id ) {

         console.log( id ); 
         // always undefined, why? (resolved)
         // this now returns "1"

         // do Stuff
         deferred.resolve( getResult );
         return deferred.promise;

     }

 );

 describe( 'Me is testing a factory', function ( ) {

     it( 'should update the name of Mr.Foo', function ( ) {

         testObj = { name: 'Mr. Foo' };
         factory.updateMe( testObj );
         $rootScope.$digest();

         console.log( factory.baz ); // { name: 'Mr. Foo', _id: '1', _rev: '1' }

         updateObj = { name: 'Mr. Nobody', _id: '1', _rev: '2' };
         factory.updateMe( updateObj );
         $rootScope.$digest();

         console.log( factory.baz );
         // This should be { name: 'Mr. Nobody', _id: '1', _rev: '2' } 
         // but instead it is { name: 'Mr. Foo', _id: '1', _rev: '1' }

     });

 });
```

I'm pretty new to Angular and Unit testing with Jasmine. Do I misunderstood something about mocking a service or am I following a complete false approach?

> I updated the Factory and the Test to be hopefully more clear about my problem.
>
> @Benjamin Gruenbaum, I added the `return` but that didn't help

Comment: Promises work on return values, `return` the inner promises

Comment: In your test file, what are result and getResult initialised to? If result is not initialised to an object with an id field, that would explain the undefined in the console.log

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the bug by myself, **silly me**. The `deferred` variable needs to be set in each `spyOn(obj, 'method').callFake()` function. Because of the variable scope I always got the `deferred.resolve` value from a previous `deferred.promise`.

```
inject( function ( _$q_, _$rootScope_, _service_) {

    $q = _$q_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    service = _service_;
   // deferred = $q.defer(); // don't set the deferred var here!

}

spyOn(service, 'save').and.callFake(
    function( obj ) {

       // do stuff to obj

       deferred = $q.defer(); // this is essential
       deferred.resolve( obj );

       return deferred.promise;

    }
);

spyOn(service, 'get').and.callFake(
    function( id ) {

       // create result var and do stuff

       deferred = $q.defer(); // this is essential
       deferred.resolve( result );

       return deferred.promise;

    }
);
```